# How do I make Nautilus show the date in the 12-hour format?

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, time

In Nautilus, I have the folder view set to the list view, and the modification date category only shows the time in the 24-hour format:

[image]

But I don't want this. I want it to display the modification time in the 12-hour format. I've set the top panel to show the time in the 12-hour format... I assumed that would carry over to other programs but I guess not? Is there any way to force the 12-hour format system wide? In System Settings my Regional Format is set to Canada.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.1.

Answer (score 2):

The setting that affects Nautilus is different to the setting that Ubuntu uses.

Set it for Nautilus with: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-format 12h`

[Bug already reported here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-datetime/+bug/1174261)